# Compiler is omitting DOCTYPE in parsed XML file, how to include this in the final file?

Tags: java, xml, processing

I'm parsing an XML file based on some arbitrary data. The final XML file is represented as a save file for another application, over which I have no control. In order to properly load it into the program however,

```
<!DOCTYPE Workspace >
```

has to be included at the top of the file. The Processing/Java XML parser, (and as far as I've been able to work out every other XML parser as well) always ignores this line.

I searched everywhere, but I have not been able to find any workaround to this. I'm not familiar with DTD's, as far as I know I don't have to either, since the Doctype definition is something beyond my control.

```
XML xml;
...


String data = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><!DOCTYPE Workspace >
xml = parseXML(data);
```

The actual result is a file in which every piece of XML is parsed properly, EXCEPT for the

```
<!DOCTYPE Workspace >
```

declaration.

Is there any workaround to this?

**EDIT:**
As requested, a sample from the XML file I'm generating:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Notice how it doesn't include <!DOCTYPE Workspace > here -->
<Workspace xmlns="http://www.qlcplus.org/workspace" CurrentWindow="FixtureManager">
  <Creator>
    <Name>Q Light Controller Plus</Name>
    <Version>4.12.1</Version>
    <Author>steph</Author>
  </Creator>
  <Engine>
    <InputOutputMap>
      <Universe ID="0" Name="Universe 0">
        <Input Line="0" Plugin="MIDI"/>
        <Output Line="6" Plugin="ArtNet"/>
        <PluginParameters outputIP="192.168.0.24"/>
      </Universe>
    </InputOutputMap>
    <Fixture>
      <Manufacturer>Generic</Manufacturer>
      <Model>Generic RGB</Model>
      <Mode>RGB</Mode>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Name>Generic RGB #1</Name>
      <Universe>0</Universe>
      <Address>0</Address>
      <Channels>3</Channels>
    </Fixture>
...
  </Engine>
</Workspace>
```

As well as the code that generates it:

```
  data = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><!DOCTYPE Workspace ><Workspace xmlns=\"http://www.qlcplus.org/workspace\" CurrentWindow=\"FixtureManager\"><Creator><Name>Q Light Controller Plus</Name><Version>4.12.1</Version><Author>steph</Author></Creator><Engine><InputOutputMap><Universe Name=\"Universe 0\" ID=\"0\"><Input Plugin=\"MIDI\" Line=\"0\"/><Output Plugin=\"ArtNet\" Line=\"6\"/><PluginParameters outputIP=\"192.168.0.24\"/></Universe></InputOutputMap>";

  for(int x = 0; x < 48; x++){
    for(int y = 0; y < 28; y ++){
      fixtureTracker++;
      String fixtureData = "<Fixture><Manufacturer>Generic</Manufacturer><Model>Generic RGB</Model><Mode>RGB</Mode><ID>" + fixtureTracker + "</ID><Name>Generic RGB #" + fixtureTracker + "</Name><Universe>" + universe + "</Universe><Address>" + address + "</Address><Channels>3</Channels></Fixture>";
      if(address > 500){
        address = 0;
        universe++;
      }else{
        address += 3;
      }
      data = data.concat(fixtureData);
    }
  }

  data = data.concat("</Engine></Workspace>");
  xml = parseXML(data);

  saveXML(xml, "xmldata.qxw");
```

I know the workspace is defined in the 3rd line, however, I still need the DOCTYPE declaration included in the generated file.

Comment: Please could you provide a [mcve]? We can't see exactly how you're parsing the XML, or what you're then doing with it. Pseudo-code isn't nearly as useful here as a complete example.

Comment: As far as I understood, you want a DOCTYPE with just the name of the document element and no other details in an XML file you're creating with your app. But that just depends on how you're creating/serializing your XML eg. there are multiple different ways to write out XML in Java. So show us your Java code that writes out the XML file. In and by itself, a DOCTYPE without an internal or external subset just asserts the expected name of the document ("root") element, and doesn't necessarily become part of the parsed representation of the XML data, depending on which Java XML API you're using.

Comment: Can you post your code about how you generate the xml file ?

Comment: Why do you first build up a string containing XML, then parse that string (as in `parseXM()`, though we don't really know what this does), then serialize the result again? With your `data` string already containing XML, all you need to do is to write it out to a file eg `new PrintStream("xmldata.qxw").println(data)`

Comment: @imhotap `parseXML()` is used to convert it to a properly parsed XML object(indentation and newlining), which is useful for future extensibility, retrievability and readability. It is mostly used to retrieve dynamic data, which is not yet the case here. Though I suppose if there is no way around my original question, I'd have to apply your suggestion.